# Speed up vba for Access

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

Excel has means to speed up macros by adding statements like

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

Whereas Access, from what I can tell, only has

```
Echo False
```

Are there other tricks? I've read [this post](http://www.fmsinc.com/tpapers/faster/#Macros%20Tips) and added Echo False and I made variables to hold control counts instead of referencing the object itself. The other tricks don't seem applicable. Converting to accde seems like it's a bit of an undertaking and my vba isn't quite ready for that yet. I've already compiled the code. Some of my subs cycle through all of the controls and changes the visible property on certain ones. This of course takes forever and I am trying to speed things up.

Comment: I'd say this is the wrong approach, change the code instead.  Why go through all controls? Can you restrict the list by control type? or by a sub container like a frame? Could you store the list, so its only slow once? Could you cheat and put a 'please wait' label in-front of everything. ACCDE wouldn't speed up the code any more than compiling it already has, accde is for code security not performance.

Comment: It cycles through the controls, but checks the controls tag for "DYNAMIC" value and if it's already visible. If both are true then it sets visible to false. There just happens to be a potential of 160 controls to change.

Comment: My original plan was to create/delete the controls, but there's that limit in control creation for forms in Access and from what I've read, I should just adjust the visible property. Somewhat ironically doing so has tanked my performance thus I ask this question.

Comment: If you have some working code, I'd suggest posting it on [CodeReview.SE]. Please follow the rules there (Title describes what the code does, body describes the how and why and indicates you're specifically looking to improve performance) - "Need it to run faster" describes about 50% of the posts there. :)

Comment: @FreeMan since I was asking if a particular feature exists in Access SuperUser made more sense. As it stands, I feel like this question is out of scope on Code Review based on [this meta post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) there. Though, I'm pretty new both here and there. Ultimately, if my question needs to be moved, I'll let a mod migrate it.

Comment: @LuxClaridge this question, _as it stands_ would immediately be closed on CR. However, it sounds like you have the basis for a really good question there "How can I improve this otherwise functional code?" Entirely up to you.

Comment: *Excel has means to speed up macros by adding statements like* That's false. If no cells affected by macro, these statements gives nothing.